# p:commandButton not firing inside p:dialog

Tags: spring, jsf

I start learning JSF and primeface.I have a xhtml page and a Dialog but actionListener in CommandButton not working when I update.
Please help me.
Here is the content of my xhtml file

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="/WEB-INF/template/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">Continents</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:head >
                <f:loadBundle basename="fst.info.memoire.bundle.messages" var="msg"/>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <div class="ui-g">
                <div class="ui-g-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <h1>Gestion des continents</h1>       
                         <h:form id="main" >
                             <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
                             <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">
                             <p:toolbar>
                                <f:facet name="left">
                                    <p:commandButton  value="Nouveau"  icon="fa fa-plus"   onclick="PF('continentAdd').show();" update=":add:displaye1" />
                                 </f:facet>
                             </p:toolbar>
                             <p:dataTable id="listTab" var="continent" value="#{continentBean.listerContinent()}" selectionMode="single" 
                             rowKey="#{continent.code}" reflow="true" selection="#{continentBean.selectedContinent}" emptyMessage="Aucun enregistrement">
                                 <f:facet name="header">Liste des continents</f:facet>
                                 <p:column headerText="Code">
                                     <h:outputText value="#{continent.code}" />
                                 </p:column>
                                 <p:column headerText="Nom" >   
                                    <h:outputText value="#{continent.nom}" />                   
                                 </p:column>
                                 <p:column headerText="Actions" >
                                     <div style="text-align: center;">
                                        <p:commandButton id="modifier" icon="fa fa-pencil" title="Modifier" />
                                        <p:commandButton id="supprimer" icon="fa fa-trash" title="Supprimer" actionListener="#{continentBean.supprimerContinent}" update=":main:listTab,:main:messages ">
                                            <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Etes vous sur de vouloir supprimer cet enregistrement?" icon="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" />
                                        </p:commandButton>
                                     </div>
                                 </p:column>
                             </p:dataTable>   
                             </h:panelGrid>
                             <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" >
                                <p:commandButton value="Oui" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="fa fa-check" />
                                <p:commandButton value="Non" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="fa fa-close" />
                            </p:confirmDialog>

                        </h:form>   
                        <p:dialog header="Ajouter un continent" widgetVar="continentAdd"
                            resizable="false" modal="true" id="addCont" >
                            <h:form id="add">
                                <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
                                <h:panelGrid id="displaye1" columns="3" cellpadding="4"
                                    style="margin:0 auto;">
                                    <p:outputLabel for="code" value="Code" />
                                    <p:inputText value="#{continentBean.code}" id="code" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['continent.code']}">
                                        <f:ajax event="blur" render="messagecode"/>
                                    </p:inputText>
                                    <p:message for="code" style="color:red" id="messagecode"/>
                                    <p:outputLabel for="nom" value="Nom" />
                                    <p:inputText value="#{continentBean.nom}" id="nom" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['continent.nom']}">
                                        <f:ajax event="blur" render="messageNom"/>
                                    </p:inputText>
                                    <p:message for="nom" style="color:red" id="messageNom"/>
                                </h:panelGrid>
                                <p:separator />
                                <div align="center">
                                    <p:commandButton value="Ajouter" update=":main:listTab,:main:messages " icon="fa fa-check" ajax="true"
                                    action="#{continentBean.ajouterContinent()}"
                                    oncomplete="PF('continentAdd').hide();" />
                                    <p:commandButton value="Annuler" icon="fa fa-close"
                                    oncomplete="PF('continentAdd').hide();" />
                                </div>
                            </h:form>
                        </p:dialog> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </h:body>


    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

and here is my backingBean

```
package fst.info.memoire.presentation.admin;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import fst.info.memoire.model.Continent;
import fst.info.memoire.service.admin.interf.ContinentService;


@Component
@ManagedBean(name="continentBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ContinentBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{continentService}")
    @Autowired
    ContinentService continentService;
    String code ;
    String nom ;
    Continent selectedContinent ;
    List<Continent> listContinent ;
    public ContinentBean() {
        super();
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
    public ContinentService getContinentService() {
        return continentService;
    }
    public void setContinentService(ContinentService continentService) {
        this.continentService = continentService;
    }
    public Continent getSelectedContinent() {
        return selectedContinent;
    }
    public void setSelectedContinent(Continent selectedContinent) {
        this.selectedContinent = selectedContinent;
    }
    public List<Continent> getListContinent() {
        return listContinent;
    }
    public void setListContinent(List<Continent> listContinent) {
        this.listContinent = listContinent;
    }

    public List<Continent> listerContinent() {
        return continentService.listContinent();
    }
    public void ajouterContinent(ActionEvent event){
        System.out.println("---------Click!");
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        try{
            Continent continent = new Continent();
            continent.setCode(this.code);
            continent.setNom(this.nom);
            continentService.ajouterContinent(continent);
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Succes", "Continent ajouté avec succès");
            context.addMessage(null, message);
        }catch(Exception e){
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Erreur", "Erreur lors de l'ajout");
            context.addMessage(null, message);
        }  

    }
    public void supprimerContinent(){
        addMessage("System Error", "Please try again later.");
    }

    public void addMessage(String summary, String detail) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, summary, detail);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }


}
```

Comment: Which commandButton is causing problems?

Comment: <p:commandButton value="Ajouter" update=":main:listTab,:main:messages " icon="fa fa-check" ajax="true"
                                    action="#{continentBean.ajouterContinent()}"
                                    oncomplete="PF('continentAdd').hide();" />

Comment: The first commandButton cause problems , not responding

Comment: Using `@Component` AND `@ManagedBean` on the same class is bound to produce problems. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387993/spring-jsf-integration-how-to-inject-a-spring-component-service-in-jsf-managed and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421777/autowired-service-inside-a-managedbean-component-class-is-null-during-jsf-req

Comment: And you usage of a template is weird... Your 'content' contains a full `h:head` and `h:body` but the title is somewhere else. So there probably/most likely is some other head/body stuff in the template that can also cause problems. And `action="#{continentBean.ajouterContinent()}"` is not compatible with `public void ajouterContinent(ActionEvent event){` Next time [mcve] please... Very, very important! What tutorial are you using? Find a different/better one... To many basic things wrong in your page/code. And whay do you use `f:ajax` insead of `p:ajax`?

Answer (score 0):

Your command button should look like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Ajouter" update=":main:listTab,:main:messages " icon="fa fa-check" 
           actionListener="#{continentBean.ajouterContinent()}"
           oncomplete="PF('continentAdd').hide();" />
```

You do not need the ajax="true", thats the default, and most important, when you are intending to do ajax calls you have to use `actionListener` instead of `action` (used for standard synchronous POST requests).

Comment: have you changed action to actionListener?

Comment: Yes I changed action to actionListener, but if I put the "update" as you recommended it does not work because these two different forms

Comment: Correct.. sorry missed that inner form. So does it work when you use the original update value?

Comment: It does not work. I tried all possible combinations but nothing. I tried to display a text when clicking on the "add" button but I do not see anything on the console

Comment: when you specify the backing bean method.. specify without the brackets: actionListener="#{continentBean.ajouterContinent}"

Comment: I made this change but there is no change

Comment: When you click on that button, is this method invoked .. {continentBean.ajouterContinent}?

Comment: When I click on the button there is only the onComplete which is executed and not the actionListener

Comment: Try to add process="@this"